# .Net Core 2.1 project doesn't use scaffolded Identity when deploying on IIS, instead uses an old template from 2016

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

My problem is the following, I have a pretty huge project where I've deployed The Identity Scaffolding, so it has scaffolded in The Areas map. When I run this project in IIS Express on Visual Studio 2016, everything works fine, but when I published it and deploy it on IIS 10 on my local pc or on an remote server with Windows 2016 and IIS 10 installed on it, he refers everytime to a default template of inlogpage.

[How it looks on IIS Express and how it should look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeciK.png)
[This how it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wrds.png)

I deploy it in the local IIS Express of Visual Studio but it doesn't in the normal IIS. [IIS Express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqMSu.png)

[Scaffolded Identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoEiW.png)

Update project is finally running had something to do with the roles on sql server, but still it doesn't explain why he isn't taking my changed my login page
[Right page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5S99.png)
[Default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ11H.png)

Answer (score 0):

Those seem to be different projects, see the year and the project name in the footers. To deploy to IIS, consider using the [Web Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/introduction-to-web-deploy) method instead the `File system` method. See [Deploy the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#deploy-the-app) for further information.

Comment: It is the same project, I just changed the names of the footer and header

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your site is using the same folder by click on the explore on the site.

[image]

do not forget to refresh the site after publishing from the visual studio.

[image]

Comment: Same project, just changed footer and header and that doesn't do a thing, it's deeper something on .csporj

Comment: could you share how you deploy the project after changes in iis? did you publish the project or just copy-paste the bin file and changed directory.